# Enable Windows Azure Subscription

Tags: azure

My windows azure subscription has been cancelled. I want to update my credit card details and enable it.So please provide steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the link below to create an incident with Windows Azure Commerce Team, and they will provide necessary assistance to get your Subscription enabled and get going:

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?prid=14234&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn&ln=en-us

Answer (score 4):

once your account has been cancelled the only way to revive it is by going to http://commerce.microsoft.com sign in, make sure you select subscription from the drop down near to your name on the top right side (to check if its the correct, select subscriptions and there should be the subscription that is cancelled) once u r under the correct one, go to payment options and add or change ur credit card... this then will update the service and resume the service... after this is done and everything is cocher, you can go to the account portal of azure and manage payment options from there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Windows Azure Account Subscriptions](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions) page and change the payment method on your chosen subscription.

Comment: Ya but if the subscription is cancelled, then change payment method is not visible.